# C++ - private data members

Tags: c++, class, object, private

If I have a class with `private` data members, for example, do I say that those data members are not accessible outside the class or they are not accessible outside the `objects` of that class?

Thanks.

Comment: @LaszloG: These links might interest you
[gotw](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/076.htm)/
[this](http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2010_07_01_archive.html)

Comment: ? Sorry, I mistook `@` function somehow...

Answer (score 3):

Technically speaking, none of the above.  You say, "Only entities that have private access to this class can access these variables."

This includes <strike>objects of that type</strike>, member functions of that type, <strike>friends of that type</strike>, member functions of friends of that type...

Actually, technically speaking, objects are incapable of accessing anything since they do not have behavior.

Answer (score 2):

`private` means that member functions of the class (and any nested types) can access those data members, given *any* instance of the class.

Answer (score 1):

If it is private, then (emphasis added):

> its *name* can be used only by members
>   and friends of the class in which it
>   is declared.

-- Stroustup's "The C++ Programming Language", and one of the draft standards.

In C++, the data itself can always be accessed by other mechanisms. The goal is to impede accidental access, even if malicious access is still feasible.

Answer (score 0):

They are not accessible outside the class's code (including derived classes); except for entities declared `friend`. As the class's code (the class member functions) are bound to the class (not the individual object), accessibility is evaluated at the class level.

```
class Foo
{
private:
    int secret;
    Foo * other;

public:
    explicit Foo(Foo* other_) : other(other_), secret(42) {}
    Foo() : other(0), secret(0) {}

    int Peek(void) { return secret; }
    int neighborPeek(void)
    {
        if (other)
            return other->secret; // this is OK, we're still inside the class
        else
            return -1;
}

int main()
{
    Foo aFoo, bFoo(&aFoo);
    std::cout << bFoo.neighborPeek(); // will dump aFoo's secret.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't they be accessed through reinterpret_casting and pointers if I'm not mistaken? Of course that would be a terrible idea though.

Comment: reinterpret_cast has a long name for a reason -- to remind you that you shouldn't use it except when there's really no alternative! You can also do evil access tricks with the preprocessor, or by mocking up an equivalent data structure with more relaxed access rules, or.... In C/C++, pretty much everything is _possible_, but if you have play tricks quite that nasty then something has gone wrong at a higher level! (And, of course, you just broke encapsulation and so all bets are off for the stability of your code against upstream implementation changes.)